# About a proof in Chapter 6 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

This is pages 126-127 from the book:

[image]
[image]
Where he says "Note that $M_i-m_i\leq2M$, and that $M_i-m_i\leq\epsilon$ unless..." I have a problem. Shouldn't it be "Note that $M_i-m_i\leq2M$, and that $\alpha(v_j)-\alpha(u_j)\leq\epsilon$ unless..." instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's correct as written. If $x_{i-1}$ is none of the $u_j$, then $x_i < x_{i-1}+\delta$, $[x_{i-1},x_i] \subset K$, and by the choice of $\delta$, it follows that $\lvert f(s) - f(t)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $s,t\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$, so $M_i - m_i \leqslant \varepsilon$.

The point is that away from the discontinuities, the partition is so fine that the upper and lower sums of the integral differ by at most $\varepsilon \cdot (b-a)$, since the oscillation of $f$ on each partition interval is small, and the set of discontinuities is caught in partition intervals of small total length.